# How to access to argparse positional arguments through namespace object in Python

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to use a positional argument through argparse, but i cannot access to this argument value...
I tried to look at the documentation from python about argparse but i didn't found anything really clear nor on the different thread...

So here is my code :

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='valid arguments')
parser.add_argument('file_liste', type=str, help='give a valid list')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

and here is the result i get:

```
Namespace(file_liste='my_list.txt')
```

that's my command line to launch my script:

```
python my_script.py my_list.txt
```

What i want is that my script take a txt file as an argument, to read it, but i can't access to this value that should be stored in the variable called 'file_liste'.

I tried this, but i get an error:

```
print(args[0], "this is args[0]")
TypeError: 'Namespace' object does not support indexing
```

It's probably a stupid thing, but i didn't found any answer that i could understand...

Comment: Try `args.file_liste`

Comment: Well, it works... I knew I was missing something, sorry for this !

Comment: related (names with hyphens): https://stackoverflow.com/q/63255485

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`args` gives you the arguments, which as the error says, doesn't support indexing.
It gives you named items, for example,

```
args.file_liste
```

will be the file list you asked for.