# Python argparse: how to reference a parameter with a dash in it

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) and I'd like to specify the positional argument with a dash in it. argparse seems to let me do this. Indeed, it shows up in the Namespace of parse_args(), but I cannot figure out how to reference the corresponding value. Here's a minimal example (notice the dash in 'a-string'):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('a-string', help='A string')

args = parser.parse_args()

# AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'a_string'
#print("Argument was: " + args.a_string)

# TypeError: 'Namespace' object is not subscriptable
#print("Argument was: " + args['a-string'])

# AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'a'
#print("Argument was: " + args.a-string)

# I give up. Ask StackOverflow.
```

I initially thought to address this with the [dest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#dest) argument to [add_argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-add-argument-method), but I get "ValueError: dest supplied twice for positional argument" if I add dest to a positional argument. How do I reference the value of this positional argument?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The arguments are given as attributes of the namespace object returned by `parse_args()`. But identifiers (including attributes) can't have a hyphen in them (at least not if you want to access them directly), because it's a minus sign, and that means something else.

If you want your argument to be named "a-string" to the user but accessible in your code as `a_string` (which was one of your attempted approaches) you can use the `metavar` argument to specify how it's described to the user.

```
parser.add_argument('a_string', help='A string', metavar='a-string')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.a_string)
```

The argument will appear in the usage information as:

```
positional arguments:
  a-string    A string
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument

Comment: 'dest' does not work for positional arguments. Note my last paragraph.

Comment: So you did. Then go the other way: have `a_string` be its actual name and use `metavar` to alter how it's shown to the user.

Comment: Ah, creative. I hadn't thought of inverting my thinking and using metavar. To be honest, I wish that argparse took 'dest' as an option for positional arguments. That would most naturally solve my problem. But your metavar idea works, so I'll use that. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I was surprised that `dest` didn't work. But it does make more sense for keyword arguments, where the variable name is actually part of the user's command.

Comment: For a positional, the first parameter is the `dest`; that's why you can't provide it again with a keyword.

Comment: Right. Unless you include a dash in the positional argument name, then you can't seem to access it. Thus allowing for dest seems to make sense. Why limit someone from naming the variable for the positional argument?

Comment: Possibly they didn't expect anyone would have a requirement to name their argument something with a dash in it.

Comment: Probably not. But that is why it is unwise to unnecessarily limit what your users can do with your interface. It's hard to anticipate what they may want or need to do with it.

Comment: `argparse` does allow you to "name" the argument with a dash in it.  You can use any `dest` you want.  But Python limits what you can use with the `args.dest` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

`dest` with a '-' is handled differently with an optional and a positional.

```
In [298]: import argparse                                                                            
In [299]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()                                                         
In [300]: a1 = parser.add_argument('--a-string');                                                 
In [301]: a2 = parser.add_argument('foo-string');                                                    
In [302]: parser.print_help()                                                                        
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--a-string A_STRING] foo-string

positional arguments:
  foo-string

optional arguments:
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit
  --a-string A_STRING
```

The `dest` for the `optional` is derived from the first 'long' flag, replacing any internal '-' with '_'.  The `dest` for the positional is the first argument, without any replacements.  You have complete control over the positional `dest`.

```
In [304]: args = parser.parse_args(['xxx'])                                                          
In [305]: args                                                                                       
Out[305]: Namespace(a_string=None, **{'foo-string': 'xxx'})
In [306]: args.a_string
```

The dash dest can be still be accessed:

```
In [307]: vars(args)['foo-string']                                                                   
Out[307]: 'xxx'
In [308]: getattr(args, 'foo-string')                                                                
Out[308]: 'xxx'
```

The '-/_' replacement is done so you can use a '-' in the flag (a common POSIX practice), but still access the attribute with the dot syntax.

Internally `argparse` uses `getattr` and `setattr` so it does not limit the `dest`.  It doesn't have to be a valid python name.  This is true for optionals as well as positionals.

If I gave the optional a `dest` value (distinct from the flag),

```
In [310]: a1.dest = 'a-string'     # changing the existing argument
                                                              
In [312]: parser.print_help()                                                                        
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--a-string A-STRING] foo-string

positional arguments:
  foo-string

optional arguments:
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit
  --a-string A-STRING
```

This changed the 'A_STRING' to 'A-STRING', but also changed the attribute name:

```
In [313]: args = parser.parse_args(['xxx'])                                                          
In [314]: args                                                                                       
Out[314]: Namespace(**{'a-string': None, 'foo-string': 'xxx'})
```

`metavar` lets us control how the value is displayed in the help.  Then we can choose the `dest` to be anything practical (or impractical if we prefer).

```
In [315]: a1.dest='a_string'; a1.metavar='MY-STRING'                                                 
In [316]: a2.dest='foo_bar'; a2.metavar='YOUR-STRING'                                                
In [317]: parser.print_help()                                                                        
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--a-string MY-STRING] YOUR-STRING

positional arguments:
  YOUR-STRING

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --a-string MY-STRING
In [318]: args = parser.parse_args(['xxx'])                                                          
In [319]: args                                                                                       
Out[319]: Namespace(a_string=None, foo_bar='xxx')
```

Ugly dest, independent of flags and metavar:

```
In [320]: a1.dest='a-#$'; a2.dest='-xxx$3'                                                           
In [321]: args = parser.parse_args(['xxx'])                                                          
In [322]: args                                                                                       
Out[322]: Namespace(**{'-xxx$3': 'xxx', 'a-#$': None})
In [323]: getattr(args, '-xxx$3')                                                                    
Out[323]: 'xxx'
In [324]: parser.print_usage()                                                                       
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--a-string MY-STRING] YOUR-STRING
```

Some have argued that positionals should perform the '-/_' replacement.  But since the `metavar` gives full control over the help display, there's no need for that.  At best if would just make `positionals` behave a bit more like `optionals.

Your options with the `metavar` are more limited.  Special characters can mess up the `usage` formatting, especially if the usage is long (multiline) or with mutually exclusive groups.  That formatting is rather brittle.